# Error ITMS-90046 after resigning app, do i need to resign each framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile, application-loader

I have resigned an app, when i try to upload it to appstore using application loader i get the following error for all the frameworks.

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, value
>   '4L27XY96BF.xx.xxx.app' for key 'application-identifier'
>   in
>   'Payload/App.app/Frameworks/xx.framework/xx'
>   is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your
>   TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier."

This is the first time that i'm running into this issue, i've resigned a ton of apps and never had this problem. For this particular app i tried iOS App Signer, AirSign, iResign, i tried to manually resign it using the terminal, but i keep getting the same error.

Do i need to manually resign each framework? If so, do i resign each framework and then resign the ipa, or do i resign the ipa and then the frameworks?

I find many examples of how to manually resign an ipa, but how do i manually resign a .framework inside of a .ipa?

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced the same error when I tried to resign an app which included an embedded framework. I unsuccessfully tried resigning the app manually using the command line and the `iResign` app.

I was finally able to successfully upload the binary after I resigned the app using fastlane.  `fastlane resign` appears to be the most up to date and best maintained tool currently available for resigning ipas.

Here is the command I used

`$ fastlane run resign ipa:"/Users/my_user/path/to/app.ipa" signing_identity:"iPhone Distribution: MY Company (XXXXXXXX)" provisioning_profile:"/Users/my_user/path/to/profile.mobileprovision" bundle_id:com.company.new.bundle.name`

Full docs here - 
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/resign/